# I want to solve a differential equation in matrix form

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I tried something like that. Z is my hamiltonian

```
n = 5;

σ2 = 0.1;

RR = RandomReal[{-Sqrt[3*σ2], Sqrt[3*σ2]}, n];

Z = Table[
    KroneckerDelta[i - j + 1] + KroneckerDelta[i - j - 1], {i, 1, 
     n}, {j, 1, n}] + DiagonalMatrix[RR];

usol = NDSolveValue[{I D[ψ[x, t], t] == 
    Z.ψ[x, t], ψ[0, t] == 0, ψ[n, t] == 0}, ψ, {t,
    0, 1}]
```

I solve the problem finding the eigenstates and eigenvalues, then I choose a one site and evolve in time but now I want to solve the differential equation directly to check my results.

Comment: ψ is undefined..

Comment: You may want to take a look at @Carl Woll's recent answer [240255](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240255).

Comment: Actually you do not provide initial conditions for ODE solver.

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci ψ is an unknown function :)

Comment: Your equation says nothing about the x dependence of the function.

Comment: btw here is another way to construct `Z=SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> RR, Band[{2, 1}] -> 1, 
  Band[{1, 2}] -> 1}, {n, n}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $\psi$ is a normalized column vector of length $n$ that does not depend on "$x$", perhaps the OP is looking for something like this (following @Carl Woll's answers [210001](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/210001/61809) and [240255](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240255/61809)):

```
SeedRandom[1234];
n = 5;
tmax = 10;
σ2 = 0.1;
ψinit = Normalize@RandomReal[1, n];
RR = RandomReal[{-Sqrt[3*σ2], Sqrt[3*σ2]}, n];
Z = Table[
    KroneckerDelta[i - j + 1] + KroneckerDelta[i - j - 1], {i, 1, 
     n}, {j, 1, n}] + DiagonalMatrix[RR];
Clear[ψ]
usol = NDSolveValue[{I D[ψ[t], t] == 
     Z . ψ[t], ψ[0] == ψinit}, ψ, {t, 0, tmax}];
Plot[Abs[usol[t]], {t, 0, tmax}]
Plot[Abs[Total@usol[t]], {t, 0, tmax}]
Manipulate[
 ReImPlot[usol[t][[i]], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotTheme -> "Web", 
  PlotLabel -> i], {i, 1, n, 1}]
```

[image: psi evolution plots]

Comment: Thanks @TimLaska is too helpful

Comment: You are welcome! Thank you for the Accept.