# how to solve matrix differential equation using Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, vector

I have to solve $[m]x''+[c]x'+[k]x=[p]$
where x is function of $t$
after defining $[m],[c],[k]$ and $[p]$ in mathematica and
`x[t_]={x1[t],x2[t],x3[t]}`

I am using NDSolve as

```
NDSolve[m.x''[t]+c.x'[t]+k.x[t]==p,x[t],{t,0,10}]
```

but I am not getting its solution even I tried

```
NDSolve[{m.x''[t]+c.x'[t]+k.x[t]==p,x[0]==0,x'[0]==0},x[t],{t,0,10}
```

can somebody help me to solve the initial equation?

Comment: You could take a look at [240947](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240947/61809) for some hints on setting up a matrix differential equation.

Comment: If 240947 does not answer your question, please edit your question to include the matrices in Mathematica format, so that readers can run your actual code.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5):

When dealing with matrix equations, I personally use `Map[]` to turn a matrix or a vector into a list of equations. Example below.

```
m = {{1, 2},{3, 4}};
c = {{5, 6},{7, 8}};
p = {1, 2};
x[t_] := {x1[t], x2[t]};

equation = m . x'[t] + c . x[t] - p;

NDSolve[
  Flatten[{
    Map[# == 0 &, equation],
    Map[# == 0 &, x[0]]
  }]
  , x[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```